# Failed to Locate files from my Hard Drive using php

Tags: php, file

I want to see a list of file from My Hard Drive using PHP..
The Php Script is available on Web server.

```
$handle = opendir('G:\Backup');
    while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))){
        if($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            echo $entry.'<br>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

I want to show list of files in My `G: Drive` and `Backup` folder inside id.

It keeps loading and then Shows `504 Gateway Time-out`

Is there any help. Please help me out.
My this File where i have these codes is located on this URL.
https://musicuploads.com.au/musicuploads/test.php

And I got this `G:\Backup` Idea from https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

please help

Comment: Your local hard drive? You cannot do that with PHP.

Comment: Then how i can do it. i really want to do it. Any Jquery or javascript..

Comment: Because it is a huge security hole most browsers do not allow it, but there is an *experimental* [technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem).

Comment: Is your webserver also your local machine, or are the webserver and your local harddrive different systems?

Comment: @Evert It is Online Web Server. Not Localhost. PHP has given the details here https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php
If you read middle of this page you will see they have given the File Address using Drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think it is possible with php, you could locate file on the web server but not on your pc.
I'd reccomand something simple for that, probably c#, you could do this part with app, and then load the data into some kind of database and display it on website.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `scandir` i have tried and it works on local host to access my other partition. Let us know your status.

```
<?php
    $dir="G:\Backup";
    $files=scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file ) {
        if($file!="."&&$file!=".."){
            echo "$file</br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: That works on YOUR machine because you are using LocalHost. It will NOT work on a web server hosted anywhere else.

Comment: No Dear, I am not Accessing through localhost. My files are on WebServer.